# Update SQL Server table using LEFT

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to update a table in sql server using the below command but I get the following error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 716
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'LEFT'

Is `LEFT` not allowed when updating? What can be used instead? Thanks

```
UPDATE DI.DBO.MHS
SET (LEFT(BATCH_DATE_2, 1) + '0' + RIGHT(BATCH_DATE_2, 6))
WHERE LEFT(BATCH_DATE_2, 1) = 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must specify the column that you want to update:

```
UPDATE DI.DBO.MHS
SET BATCH_DATE_2 = LEFT(BATCH_DATE_2,1) + '0' + RIGHT(BATCH_DATE_2,6)
WHERE LEFT(BATCH_DATE_2,1) = 2
```

If it is not `BATCH_DATE_2` the column that you want to update then use that column after `SET`.

Comment: Thank you! Have a nice day.